# Почему выводит ошибку "Не существует в текущем контексте"?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

         void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd",
                Arguments = "/c time /t",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                WindowStyle=ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            });

                label1.Text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка "имя label1 не существует в текущем контексте"

Comment: А label на форме есть?

Comment: @LiptonDev вроде нет (

Comment: @LiptonDev , я так понял что label это зарезервированная какая-то переменная , а label1 это что-то типо класса или переменной (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kUlRYAPyzw&t=758s&ab_channel=XpucT) ссылка на видео где делают данную форму

Comment: Вам в конструкторе необходимо добавить элемент Label, потом установить ему свойство Name в любое для вас удобное (например: myLabel), затем уже в коде ссылаться на этот лейбл: myLabel.Text = "Hello!";